# Why is there a random gap before my element in a div?

Tags: html, css

This is my first time creating a site, I'm writing to write the css but I'm stuck on this tiny little thing. So I want the the Previous and Next to be evenly spaced and centered, but there seems to be a gap before previous which is throwing the whole thing off center. I tried to center allight, tried inline-block, tried floating but it's always there. How do I get rid of it?

My Html:

```
  <div class="print">
    <p>Print this article</p>
  </div>

  <div class="social_media">
    <!-- the sharing and social media will go here-->
    <p>Share to:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="../img/whatsapp-fill.svg" alt="whatsapp icon"/></li>
      <li><img src="../img/facebook-fill.svg" alt="facebook icon"/></li>
      <li><img src="../img/twitter-fill.svg" alt="twitter icon"/></li>
      <li><img src="../img/pinterest-fill.svg" alt="pinterest icon"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="article_nav">
    <a href="#">Previous</a>
    <a href="#">Next</a>
  </div>
```

My CSS

```
.social_media p {
  float: left;
  margin-right: .75em;
}
.social_media ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.social_media ul img, .social_media ul li {
  max-width: 1em;
  display: inline;
}

.article_nav {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}


footer {
  float: inherit;
  font: 0.8em "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 63);
}
```

This is how it appears on the site:[as you can see, its offcenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E01cA.png)

I want there to be as  much space between Previous and Next and I want them to be aligned at the center.

I think there's something with the .social_media div because when I change the order of the html to this:

```
  <div class="social_media">
    <!-- the sharing and social media will go here-->
    <p>Share to:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="../img/whatsapp-fill.svg" alt="whatsapp icon"/></li>
      <li><img src="../img/facebook-fill.svg" alt="facebook icon"/></li>
      <li><img src="../img/twitter-fill.svg" alt="twitter icon"/></li>
      <li><img src="../img/pinterest-fill.svg" alt="pinterest icon"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="print">
    <p>Print this article</p>
  </div>

  <div class="article_nav">
    <a href="#">Previous</a>
    <a href="#">Next</a>
  </div>
```

Here the space intensifies, as can be seen in this photo: [now print is spaced too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRs5y.png)

Comment: please share a code example that reproduces your problem. Otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: it most likely has something to do with how your div is interacting with the other elements above it... and/or the a tags with the elements above

Comment: we need to see what the CSS is for those other elements too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  .article_nav {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .article_nav a {
      padding: 30px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked!

Comment: your welcome, and if this worked just leave a vote  :D